# ¿Se podría bloquear el uso de ciertas palabras en los títulos para mejorar la calidad de las preguntas?

Tags: característica-nueva

En stackoverflow.com si en el título de una pregunta usas palabras como *problem* no te deja postearla al ser un término demasiado genérico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se podría implementar esta funcionalidad en la versión en español?

Comment: No creo que sea un duplicado, yo no digo mostrar una advertencia (que también) si no simplemente no dejar postear la pregunta si en el título se identifican una serie de palabras clave que sean muy genéricas

Comment: con la misma funcionalidad se pueden hacer las dos cosas... advertir o bloquear (así hacemos con las etiquetas quemadas)